# How do i run Node JS in "Output" panel of vscode without installing any extensions?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm just tried to create a restAPI with node JS and mongoDB, and with nodemon i can *re run "node myfileserver.js"* whenever i've change any file within it,

but in vscode, i can't clear the terminal panel, so i decide to find a way in google to move the output of terminal into `Output` panel of vscode like this:
[image]

unfortunately, i'm not yet find any good step to start,

anyone can guide me how do i "move" `Terminal` panel output into `Output` panel?

Comment: you don't need to move anything, did you try creating a launch configuration for your Node.js code?

Comment: @tHeSiD i've tried to created launch.json, but all this method only work when debugging, i dont really like to debug the apps instead i just need to show the log in Output Panel.